# Between 'decide' and 'an object', are prepositions like 'on, upon, about' extraneous?

Tags: grammaticality, differences, prepositions

Caution: This question concerns the verb 'direct' followed immediately afterwards by an object.
To ameliorate readability, I eschew the use of blockquotes below, where I quoted the OED.

> [[Source:]](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62843/50720) [...] [In] a sentence with a single object (instead of a phrase that begins with a determiner such as "**what** to put on sale" or "**which** question to answer"), 
>   the preposition is needed.

Is  above quote correct? It answers the entitled question  in the negative. 
Below, OED matches each definition of transitive-direct **decide** with a definition of transitive-INdirect **decide**.
Because 1a means the same as 1b, and 1d as 1e, prepositions like '*on, upon, about*' appear extraneous. If I erred, then what are the functions and meanings of the postverbal preposition?

However, I recognise the necessity of some postverbal prepositions like 'between', because
'an arbiter decided X and Y'  differs from   'an arbiter decided BETWEEN X and Y'.

---

[decide, v.<sup>1</sup>](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/48173?rskey=FJBEdB&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)   [=]   I. To come or bring to a resolution or conclusion.
 1.   a. *trans.* To arrive at an opinion or conclusion about [...]
b. *intr.* To come to a decision or conclusion. Chiefly with *on, upon, about*, etc.

d. *trans.* With infinitive, clause, or direct speech as object. To determine upon as a course of action; to resolve to do (something) or bring (something) about. Also in passive with anticipatory *it*.
e. *intr.* Chiefly with *on, upon*, etc. To come to a firm decision with regard to future action or intention; to determine on or opt for something; to select something from several alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which meaning of **decide** is involved.

That uppercut decided *the boxing match*.   [concluded, determined]

They decided *upon* the green rug.  [chose]

They decided *which* rug to place in the foyer.   [chose]